# How to deploy the model in Deep Lab V2

Tags: caffe

I am trying to train and test the Deep CNN model for segmentation. I am using the model from [Deep Lab V2](https://bitbucket.org/aquariusjay/deeplab-public-ver2) based on Caffe. I have successfully gone through the tutorial of the script of  run_pascal.sh to  train the model. However, if I want to train my own segmentation model and deploy it, how should I write the deploy.prototxt file? Can anyone provide an example of the deploy file according to their latest V2 version?

Answer (score 0):

## I used to train the model using CMD:

caffe.bin train --solver=solver.prototxt

## My solver.prototxt is as follows:

train_net: "train.prototxt"

lr_policy: "poly"

power: 0.9

base_lr: 5e-2

average_loss: 1

display: 20

max_iter: 10000

weight_decay: 0.0005

snapshot: 10000

snapshot_prefix: "/path/to/save/snapshots"

type: "AdaDelta"

solver_mode: GPU

## train.prototxt is the model used to train

## make sure to include the paths wherever necessary

Comment: So the images I'm using have only 3 classes and are size 1000x1000, do I need to configure the parameters in train.prototxt to get this working?

Comment: yes you have to set image size, rather the size to which you want the network to crop the images in IMAGE_SEG_DATA layer.

Comment: Hmmm, but when you run it on the regular PASCAL dataset, you have a varying input image size since that dataset has various image sizes?

Comment: all the images will be cropped to the size you input in train.prototxt